# Will Photoshop work on Ubuntu?

Tags: photoshop

I was using Windows XP, I like Ubuntu, but I'm wondering,because as  I'm a professional photographer & photo editor.

I do my work with Photoshop, so will photoshop work in ubuntu?

Comment: Please post your printer problem as a new question, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Photoshop or Paint.NET](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Wine (available from the Software Center) to run Photoshop. According to [the WineHQ AppDB's entry for Photoshop](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607), Photoshop is working relatively well under wine. Don't expect perfection, though, and if you run into problems, consult the entry. Not the different Wine versions mentioned; you may have to use [the Wine PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa).

Before you make a purchase, try Gimp, the relatively bitmap-based image manipulation software available from the Software Center. For something more akin to Illustrator that is vector-based, try Inkscape.

You can [install Windows in a virtual machine](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=askubuntu%20windows%20virtualbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=install%20windows%20in%20virtualbox), if your system is powerful enough - Photoshop is a very big program.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no, although there are so many people begging Adobe to bring the suite to Linux systems they refuse - no financial intensive for them.

I do believe running it under [Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop) works although not well and not the latest version.

There are alternatives; I would recommend [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), it's open source and comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this question for Photoshop alternatives: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net)

It is possible to run Windows in a Virtual Box to run Photoshop on; have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109651/use-photoshop-in-virtualbox-is-it-worth-the-hassle) for information on that too.

In addition take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36585/wine-or-virtual-machine-virtualbox-to-run-apps-eg-photoshop) for more information on running Photoshop in Wine or a Virtual Box.

Personally I would suggest that you should find and learn how to use an alternative application as this will ensure less problems in the future. Try Gimp from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 3):

[The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is as close as you can get.

As to running Photoshop and its variants under Wine, please consult the [Wine Applications Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=vendor&iId=12&sAction=view&sTitle=View%20Developer) and check for your version, as you have not specified which version and edition you have.  Wine alone would not work; you should install Wine, winetricks, Wine Windows Program Loaded, Q4Wine, and Play on Linux. For security purposes, also suggest you delete the Z: drive mapping in Wine's configuration.

Comment: Why would you need anything other than wine and winetricks? Play on Linux has nothing to do with it for example. You can find the official Ubuntu docs on Photoshop+Wine [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AdobePhotoshop).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use photoshop but also want to use linux such as Ubuntu There are 2 ways of doing it.

1. I advise you to make your PC dual boot. There are many tutorials available on How to dual boot. With this you can do both the work of windows and linux.
2. Install a virtual machine such as VMware in the ubuntu and then install the windows image on it and run windows application on it such as photoshop. But this will slow down your computer speed as two OS will simultaneously operate.